# Python pandas groupby agg function on datetime columns

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, null, aggregate

There is some bogus behaviour at `.agg()` function in pandas 0.17.1 and numpy 1.10.1. The problem can be found in some datatype conversion. Here is an example dataframe:

```
import datetime as dt

df_data = [[1,1,2]
    , ['foo', 'bar', 'bar'], [1,2,3]
    , [dt.date(2015,1,5), dt.date(2015,1,3), dt.date(2015,1,15)]
    , [dt.datetime(2015,1,5,23,16,59), dt.datetime(2015,1,5,21,16,59)
    , dt.datetime(2015,1,5,20,16,59)]
    , [dt.timedelta(minutes=60), dt.timedelta(minutes=120), dt.timedelta(minutes=12)]]

df_cols = ['gb', 'a_string', 'a_int', 'a_date', 'a_datetime', 'a_timedelta']

df = pd.DataFrame({i:j for i,j in zip(df_cols, df_data)})

print(df[df_cols])
```

The result is:

```
   gb a_string  a_int      a_date          a_datetime  a_timedelta
0   1      foo      1  2015-01-05 2015-01-05 23:16:59     01:00:00
1   1      bar      2  2015-01-03 2015-01-05 21:16:59     02:00:00
2   2      bar      3  2015-01-15 2015-01-05 20:16:59     00:12:00
```

I want to calculate for example `min()` and some other statistics. I can use several [groupby object attribute](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#groupby-object-attributes) to get my stats (let's see only `min()`):

```
df_g = df.groupby('gb').min()
print(df_g[df_cols[1:]])
```

The result is correct:

```
   a_string  a_int      a_date          a_datetime  a_timedelta
gb                                                             
1       bar      1  2015-01-03 2015-01-05 21:16:59     01:00:00
2       bar      3  2015-01-15 2015-01-05 20:16:59     00:12:00
```

Or I can use the `agg()` function, but with this, some datatype conversion error occurs at `timedelta` objects:

```
df_g_2 = df.groupby('gb').agg({i:np.min for i in df_cols[1:]})
print(df_g_2[df_cols[1:]])
```

This is the result:

```
   a_string  a_int      a_date          a_datetime    a_timedelta
gb                                                               
1       bar      1  2015-01-03 2015-01-05 21:16:59  3600000000000
2       bar      3  2015-01-15 2015-01-05 20:16:59   720000000000
```

The same error occurs at `datetime` objects if there are only `NaT` values present in a group. Let's see a new dataframe:

```
df_data = [[1,1,2]
    , ['foo', 'bar', 'bar'], [1,2,3]
    , [dt.date(2015,1,5), dt.date(2015,1,3), dt.date(2015,1,15)]
    , [pd.NaT, pd.NaT
    , dt.datetime(2015,1,5,20,16,59)]
    , [dt.timedelta(minutes=60), dt.timedelta(minutes=120), dt.timedelta(minutes=12)]]

df_cols = ['gb', 'a_string', 'a_int', 'a_date', 'a_datetime', 'a_timedelta']

df = pd.DataFrame({i:j for i,j in zip(df_cols, df_data)})

print(df[df_cols])
```

The result is:

```
   gb a_string  a_int      a_date          a_datetime  a_timedelta
0   1      foo      1  2015-01-05                 NaT     01:00:00
1   1      bar      2  2015-01-03                 NaT     02:00:00
2   2      bar      3  2015-01-15 2015-01-05 20:16:59     00:12:00
```

The `min()` works perfectly:

```
   a_string  a_int      a_date          a_datetime  a_timedelta
gb                                                             
1       bar      1  2015-01-03                 NaT     01:00:00
2       bar      3  2015-01-15 2015-01-05 20:16:59     00:12:00
```

But the `agg()` gives wrong values:

```
   a_string  a_int      a_date               a_datetime    a_timedelta
gb                                                                    
1       bar      1  2015-01-03                      nan  3600000000000
2       bar      3  2015-01-15 1420489019000000000.0000   720000000000
```

Be careful & have nice day!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If this is a bug report, wouldn't it be better submitted as an issue on [github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues)?

Comment: I'm not saying there isn't  an issue here, though I don't know if it's specifically with `agg` both `df_g_2 = df.groupby('gb').agg("min")` and `df_g_2 = df.groupby('gb').agg(lambda x: x.min())` use `agg` and give the output you are expecting